# Can't get background images to appear

Tags: html, css

I have this picture saved in the same folder as the html file yet it still wont open can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Computer Systems</title>
     </head>


 <body background=“F50 Gallery Black 005.jpg”>

 <h1>Computer System Designs</h1>


<h2>What are computer systems?</h2>
<p>Computer systems are a set of hardware devices like a monitor (screen),<br> a central processing unit (CPU), keyboard and mouse that are connected together and run software programs such as Microsoft word, antivirus, paint, google chrome etc </p>


<h2>How are they designed?</h2>
<p>Computer systems are designed by</p>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest adding the background image from CSS. Use `body{ background-image: url() }`

Comment: The quotes should be `""` not `“”`. Also you should use CSS `background` property instead as the HTML background attribute is not supported in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Body background is not supported any longer. Use CSS instead

```
<body style="background-image:url('F50 Gallery Black 005.jpg')">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the same thing as Snehal Shah.

This is a usefull link on the topic. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Long story short:

```
body {
background: url(005.jpg) 0 0;
}
```

ps: It seems that your title is off as well. Never use spaces in a image title

Answer (score 0):

@JayG747 Use CSS for style in your site, visit the following link for examples, in case, use:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Computer Systems</title>
     </head>
     <style type="text/css">
         body{
            background-image: url('F50_Gallery_Black_005.jpg'); <!-- Avoid special characters and blank spaces in filenames. -->
         }
     </style>

 <body>

 <h1>Computer System Designs</h1>


<h2>What are computer systems?</h2>
<p>Computer systems are a set of hardware devices like a monitor (screen),<br> a central processing unit (CPU), keyboard and mouse that are connected together and run software programs such as Microsoft word, antivirus, paint, google chrome etc </p>


<h2>How are they designed?</h2>
<p>Computer systems are designed by</p>
</body>



</html>
```

note: it is better to enter the styles of your site in a separate file with .css extension and insert it in your html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```